# Create a long data format and a week variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I want to transform the following data frame from wide to long with the dplyr library and consequently add a new column which gives the value of 1 to 7 ( those are the week numbers).

Basically, ID1 should get the values of AI_1, AI_2, AI_3, AI_4, AI_5, AI_6, AI_7 in a new column with a new name AI. and so forth for ID2, ID3, and ID4 and activity1...., activity7. And finally a new variable WEEK that contains the values 1 to 7 per IDn

I tried and use the following code but it does not work.

```
df_long <-
  df4 %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(ID, x1.time), names_to = "Parameters", values_to = "AI") %>%
  mutate(Time = parse_number(Parameters),
         MeanNames = case_when(grepl("AI", Parameters) ~ "AI",
                               grepl("Activity", Parameters) ~ "Activity" %>%
  select(ID,Time,AI,activity) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = MeanNames,values_from =AI_mean)
```

```
    structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", 
"ID14", "ID15", "ID16", "ID17", "ID18", "ID19", "ID2", "ID20", 
"ID21", "ID22", "ID23", "ID24", "ID25", "ID26", "ID27"), x1.time = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), activity1 = c(0, 
0.363888888888889, 0.286111111111111, 0.531944444444444, 0.290972222222222, 
0.382638888888889, 0.334722222222222, 0.557638888888889, 0.238888888888889, 
0.154166666666667, 0, 0, 0.448611111111111, 0.124305555555556, 
0.290972222222222, 0.131944444444444, 0.255555555555556, 0.252777777777778, 
0.215277777777778, 0.303472222222222), activity2 = c(0.303472222222222, 
0.2875, 0.294444444444444, 0.280555555555556, 0.304861111111111, 
0.359722222222222, 0.347916666666667, 0.264583333333333, 0.19375, 
0.171527777777778, 0.291666666666667, 0.297222222222222, 0.213888888888889, 
0.222222222222222, 0.304861111111111, 0.113888888888889, 0.208333333333333, 
0.324305555555556, 0.234027777777778, 0.364583333333333), activity3 = c(0.232638888888889, 
0.323611111111111, 0.2, 0.222222222222222, 0.323611111111111, 
0.390972222222222, 0.381944444444444, 0.306944444444444, 0.19375, 
0.263888888888889, 0.263194444444444, 0.228472222222222, 0.248611111111111, 
0.313194444444444, 0.323611111111111, 0.0840277777777778, 0.189583333333333, 
0.394444444444444, 0.302777777777778, 0.442361111111111), activity4 = c(0.228472222222222, 
0.359722222222222, 0.261111111111111, 0.275694444444444, 0.252777777777778, 
0.331944444444444, 0.309027777777778, 0.274305555555556, 0.232638888888889, 
0.277777777777778, 0.270138888888889, 0.207638888888889, 0.288888888888889, 
0.210416666666667, 0.252777777777778, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), activity5 = c(0.348611111111111, 
0.33125, 0.261805555555556, 0.409722222222222, 0.342361111111111, 
0.372916666666667, 0.193055555555556, 0.208333333333333, 0.286111111111111, 
0.290972222222222, 0.691666666666667, 0.275, 0.25625, 0.294444444444444, 
0.342361111111111, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), activity6 = c(0.215972222222222, 
0.159027777777778, 0.10625, 0.155555555555556, NA, 0.263888888888889, 
0.227777777777778, 0.125, 0.234027777777778, 0.232638888888889, 
NA, 0.198611111111111, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), activity7 = c(0.123611111111111, 
0.129861111111111, 0.167361111111111, 0.224305555555556, NA, 
0.347916666666667, 0.203472222222222, 0.190972222222222, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.190277777777778, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AI_1 = c(0.393672183448241, 
0.438868800326202, 0.301835910942944, 0.40417558245206, 0.642022052126492, 
0.142408584001277, 0.563028495670381, 0.118116816566331, 0.436212462794191, 
0.514300047314275, 0.257247546067607, 0.335604284591974, 0.291193390934394, 
0.341934289475186, 0.642022052126492, 0.324860973193389, 0.557537537102492, 
0.247198790391852, 0.280429188867851, 0.327332083531813), AI_2 = c(0.44750235206392, 
0.46972327227022, 0.173959743093479, 0.421306848407757, 0.218793365833983, 
0.168790497373066, 0.445596632079763, 0.364687582621664, 0.336361741323463, 
0.319688614645366, 0.168382532506642, 0.254056078037093, 0.21746835769531, 
0.160789612606635, 0.218793365833983, 0.266311313005776, 0.176325908027991, 
0.312408009841627, 0.169341786618747, 0.356053484162169), AI_3 = c(0.390957508679111, 
0.307322261599723, 0.145575504943204, 0.387689075911702, 0.427994003058763, 
0.151832437379957, 0.387053429665751, 0.119132014224298, 0.34516992971253, 
0.47310811763004, 0.313667364304496, 0.295658016477924, 0.397331683205576, 
0.441376185979552, 0.427994003058763, 0.177419794042628, 0.232604123120372, 
0.35835034138553, 0.166844732038584, 0.262686661252918), AI_4 = c(0.292133451860516, 
0.627664748633739, 0.168042970470727, 0.191594272379608, 0.246615732293793, 
0.13833361951739, 0.717029959712378, 0.494249194948433, 0.410376411198318, 
0.352738104642845, 0.179616804877742, 0.15798984548373, 0.19307993691809, 
0.191789936049133, 0.246615732293793, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AI_5 = c(0.137422020311649, 
0.47671458715848, 0.318789374750512, 0.0991406883545277, 0.572774291410116, 
0.36272185628419, 0.163807707465756, 0.276116364601869, 0.424367165540981, 
0.0812096382549585, 0.158958073184742, 0.246078855017164, 0.134373938223757, 
0.221318159585512, 0.572774291410116, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AI_6 = c(0.237710368521645, 
0.249932172314976, 0.129535724382782, 0.228112502799076, NA, 
0.161907840368906, 0.267396839935385, 0.239625058217238, 0.269110377528862, 
0.0783380834367801, NA, 0.152294273122736, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), AI_7 = c(0.122793946391041, 0.340170989947673, 0.409484578569937, 
0.345311080770631, NA, 0.131960673054408, 0.427318121458564, 
0.245755226369851, NA, NA, NA, 0.140419853417226, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

It should look similar to the following dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `names_to` with `.value` and define the pattern in `names_pattern` (here, the first group is either `"activity"` or `"AI"`, and the second group is the digit, `\\d`). The name of the column is given by the name of the group in the same position as `.value` (here, first one).

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, x1.time), 
               names_to = c(".value", "Time"),
               names_pattern = "(activity|AI)_*(\\d)")
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 140 × 5
   ID    x1.time Time  activity    AI
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ID1        NA 1        0     0.394
 2 ID1        NA 2        0.303 0.448
 3 ID1        NA 3        0.233 0.391
 4 ID1        NA 4        0.228 0.292
 5 ID1        NA 5        0.349 0.137
 6 ID1        NA 6        0.216 0.238
 7 ID1        NA 7        0.124 0.123
 8 ID10       NA 1        0.364 0.439
 9 ID10       NA 2        0.288 0.470
10 ID10       NA 3        0.324 0.307
# … with 130 more rows
```